# Condicionales IF y ELSE en Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Mi algoritmo debe validar lo siguiente:

Cuando edad sea de 0 a 17 años tomar jugo de naranja, 18 a 39 años tomar cerveza y 40 a 99 años tomar café.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
let edad = 15 //¿Tu que edad tienes?
let trago = '';
    
if (edad >= 18 <= 39){
  trago = 'Cerveza';
}else if(edad <= 40 <=99){
  trago = 'Cafe';
}
else{
  trago = 'Jugo de Naranja';
}
console.log(trago);
```

El problema es que siempre me muestra "cerveza".

Comment: Alguien me ayudar. me sale error =(

Comment: Explica también cual es el problema que tienes (Error, no funciona, etc.), así como está tu pregunta carece de detalles. ;)

Comment: A simple vista te faltan los operadores && entre condiciones.

Comment: Buenas, Haziel, a ver, deberías investigar un poco como se escriben en javascript las expresiones booleanas, que son las que se usan en las condiciones de los if. Que la edad esté comprendida entre los 18 y los 39 años, ambos inclusive, se escribe (edad >= 18) && (edad <=39)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El error es que no armas bien las condiciones, una de las formas correctas seria

`if(edad >=18 && edad <= 39){...}`

```js
let edad = 15;
let trago;

if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 39){
  trago = 'Cerveza';
}else if(edad >= 40 && edad <= 99){ 
// aca hay un problema de lógica, 
// te devolveria los que tienen 
// menos de 99 años y los que tienen menos
// de 40. Es redundante. Probablemente sea
// edad >= 40 && edad <= 99
  trago = 'Cafe';
}
else{
  trago = 'Jugo de Naranja';
}
console.log(trago);
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, Dios te bendiga!

Comment: @HazielSaavedra si la respuesta ha solucionado tu problema debes marcarla como aceptada :D

Comment: @Christian No sabía, soy nuevo xd, voy a aceptar. Gracias =)